# MYSQL - Copy Data to Another Database

Tags: mysql, database, copy

I want to copy the **Data** in `tempTable` from `Database1` to `Database2`, I have tried but what's with my code:

```
INSERT INTO Database1.tempTable 
FROM Database2.tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is

```
INSERT INTO Database.Table1(field 1, field 2,...)
SELECT * FROM Database2.Table2;


INSERT INTO Database1.tempTable (field 1, field 2,...)
SELECT * FROM Database2.tempTable
```

You can also use

```
  INSERT INTO Database2.Table SELECT * from Database1.Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is like this

```
INSERT INTO database2.table2 SELECT * from database1.table1
```